# Variable sorting in XSLT 1.0

Tags: sorting, xslt

Let's say I have following source XML:

```
<products>
   <product type="x" titleOne="some title" titleTwo="some other title"/>
   <product type="y" titleOne="one more title" titleTwo="and another title"/>
</products>
```

The real case obviously is more complex, but this example should be enough to illustrate.

Output should be like this:

```
<products>
   <product title="and another title"/>
   <product title="some title"/>
</products>
```

Note that:

- The title chosen depends on the `type` attribute. (Easy)
- I want the list to be sorted based on the chosen title. (Difficult)

Is this type of dynamic sorting possible in XSLT 1.0? Alternatively, is there a way of doing this in XSLT 2/3?

The ideal solution would be:

```
<xsl:for-each select="products/product">
   <xsl:variable name="myTitle">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@type = 'x'">
           <xsl:value-of select="@titleOne"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type = 'y'">
           <xsl:value-of select="@titleTwo"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="subproduct/@title"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:sort select="$myTitle"/>
   <product title="{$myTitle}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But unfortunately my XSLT processor doesn't like having a variable before sorting.

Any ideas?

Comment: "*The title chosen depends on the type attribute.*"  How exactly?

Comment: You need to show `<!--logic for title-->` to allow us to tell whether it can be done directly for the `xsl:sort select`.

Comment: Logic has been added.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you could put that logic into a function defined with `xsl:function` and then call it where you want to use the value. Also XSLT/XPath 2.0 has an `if` expression so you can write the logic more compact and directly as an XPath expression instead of the more verbose `xsl:choose/xsl:when`.

Comment: Why did you tag the question "saxon" and ask for an XSLT 1.0 solution? I'm deleting the Saxon tag as there's nothing specific to Saxon here. Ditto for msxml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot sort by a variable. Either calculate the title twice:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <xsl:sort select="@titleOne[../@type='x'] | @titleTwo[../@type='y']"/>
            <product title="{@titleOne[../@type='x'] | @titleTwo[../@type='y']}"/>      
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or use a variable to pre-process the products with the correct title, then sort the result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="products">
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <product>       
                <xsl:attribute name="title">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@type='x'">
                           <xsl:value-of select="@titleOne"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="@type='y'">
                           <xsl:value-of select="@titleTwo"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($products)/product">
            <xsl:sort select="@title"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt to answer this sub-question:

> Alternatively, is there a way of doing this in XSLT 2/3?

One way of doing this in 2.0 is to define the sort key as a function:

```
   <xsl:function name="f:myTitle" as="xs:string">
     <xsl:param name="product" as="element(product)"/>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$product/@type = 'x'">
           <xsl:value-of select="$product/@titleOne"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$product/@type = 'y'">
           <xsl:value-of select="$product/@titleTwo"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="$product/subproduct/@title"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>
```

and then invoke this function to compute the sort key:

```
   <xsl:for-each select="product">
      <xsl:sort select="f:myTitle(.)"/>
      <product title="{f:myTitle(.)}"/>      
   </xsl:for-each>
```

This still has the drawback of computing the title twice. You might hope that the optimizer will avoid this (though Saxon doesn't). In 3.0 you could define it as a memo function so the results are remembered, but that might incur an expensive amount of memory in relation to the benefits.

In 3.0 you could create a map containing the keys and the associated products (I'm assuming you actually want to output more information about the product, not just the computed title):

```
   <xsl:variable name="product-map" 
        select="map:merge(product!map{f:myTitle(.) : .})"/>

   <xsl:for-each select="map:keys($product-map)">
      <xsl:sort select="."/>
      <product title="{.}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$product-map(.)"/>
      </product>      
   </xsl:for-each>
```

If the product titles are unique then you could do a pseudo-grouping operation, to take advantage of the current-grouping-key() function, for which there is no analogue with sorting:

```
   <xsl:for-each-group select="product" group-by="f:myTitle(.)">
      <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      <product title="{current-grouping-key()}"/>      
   </xsl:for-each>
```

And finally, with XSLT 3.0 + XPath 3.1, you could take advantage of the `fn:sort` function and the array data type:

```
<xsl:for-each select="sort(product![f:myTitle#1, .], 
                       function($p){$p(1)})">
   <product title="{.(1)}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select=".(2)"/>
   </product>
</xsl:for-each>
```